# How do I add character requirements for factions or guilds?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

Is it possible to add character requirements to joining a faction or path, and therefore cause a character to be unable to join, say, the Mages Guild, or the Thieves Guild?

For example, I don't like the idea that my Orc, who has 80 in archery, heavy armor, two-handed, and single handed fighting, but a <18 in all the magic schools, is easily welcomed into the Mage College. Or that he is asked to join the Thieves Guild. It really ruins immersion for me.

Comment: Once the Creation Kit is released, the sky(rim) is the limit for mods.  You could create this mod if you wanted.

Comment: Are you saying that the mod was not made for previous versions, or just stating that if I wanted to I could?  (I know I could, but I won't want to, and I'm curious if someone did something like this in the past)

Comment: This was the way Factions in vanilla Morrowind.  I'm not sure about Oblivion.  My main point was the question "Are there plans for X mod?" are pretty vague and localized.

Comment: In oblivion you could join everything with no restrictions that I can remember.

Comment: Voting to reopen as per this meta post: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5547/closed-mod-recommendation-skyrim-question-can-this-question-be-improved-and

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some mods I found that add requirements on factions or guilds, before allowing you to join:

### Oblivion

#### [Guild Skill Requirements](https://www.gamefront.com/games/the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion/file/guild-skill-requirements)

Adds skill requirements for the Fighters Guild, Mages Guild, and the Thieves Guild.

#### [Choices and Consequences](https://www.nexusmods.com/oblivion/mods/14560)

> This mod centers on the Mages and Fighters guilds, changing them so that you will need to reach a certain proficiency in skills before being allowed to advance in rank. It bases on faction reputation + skill requirements.

#### [Higher Independent Thievery Requirements](https://www.nexusmods.com/oblivion/mods/23149)

> This mod changes the Thieves' Guild quest "Independent Thievery", dramatically raising the amount you need to fence in order to get your next commission job, in comparison to vanilla Oblivion. There are two versions. The normal version (IThieveryRaise.esp) is tougher than Vanilla, but the Very Hard version (IThieveryRaiseVeryHard.esp) is absolutely ridiculous, and only for people who LOVE to steal.

---

### Skyrim

#### [College of Winterhold Entry Requirements](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/38448)

> This mod adds skill requirements to join the College of Winterhold. It is fully voiced because Bethesda planned to have requirements to join the College at one point and recorded lines for being rejected. Also, when Faralda tests your magical prowess, she will test you on your highest skill instead of randomly selecting one of the schools of magic. You can still bypass the test by showing Faralda that you are Dragonborn during the main quest, or with persuasion, just like in vanilla.

> The requirements are fully customizable using the MCM. You can set a skill level requirement in one school of magic, and set a requirement for a certain skill level with the other four. You can also set a Magicka and level requirement. I kept a wide range of available values to account for uncappers and 1.9's removal of the level limit.

#### [Enhanced Skyrim Factions - The Companions Guild](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/22650)

> Increases the number of radiant quests required to advance in the guild, and add skill, level, and time requirements for each of the
> guild's milestone story quests.

#### [Minimum Skill Requirements For Guild Quests](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/19970)

> Current Factions with min requirements:
> Mages Guild: All schools of magic require the player to have their skills at level 30 or above
> Thieves Guild: Sneak, Lockpicking, and Pickpocketing are all required to be at level 30 or above

#### [Thieves Guild Requirements - No Auto Quest Start Brynjolf](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/14157)

> In order to trigger the beginning of the Thieves Guild quest, the player must have stolen items, picked pockets, and have some skill in sneak. Otherwise, Brynjolf will not approach you and the dialogue options with him will not appear.
>
> The requirements are as follows:
>
> - Items Stolen >= 250
> - Pockets Picked >= 25
> - Sneak skill level >= 25
>
> All three requirements must be met.
>
> Beginning in version 1.3, the requirements can now be fully
> customized.